# Instagram Automation

Tags: python, automation, scripting, instagram, instagram-api

I have 1 million+ base on instagram. I receive thousands of requests daily. I want to write automation script to automatically accept follow requests.

I know there are few paid websites which offers this job but i want to automate this and save money. There's a selenium and python thing which i saw when i googled but i am not sure if that will work or not, or maybe i can work but i am not sure of the speed.

Can someone just suggest me how to do? I am not asking for any logic or something but just an help with how it can be done?

Comment: Have you done anything so far?

Comment: Nope. Still looking for answers. I found in google “instabot” but in that readme files, its written that if you use instabot then your Instagram account will get blocked. Do you know anything regarding this?